# Jquery form submit not successful?

Tags: jquery, jqueryform

I have a jQuery function like this:

```
$(function(){
    function unshareDialog(event) {
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:200,
            width: 365,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
              "Unshare": function() {
                  $('#unshare_form').submit();
              },
              Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
              }
            }
          });
          return false;
    }
    $('#unshare_entire_file').click(unshareDialog);
});
```

My form has two submit buttons like this:

```
<form action="/unshare/" id="unshare_form" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Unshare" name="unshare_to_user" id="unshare_to_user" />
    <input type="submit" value="Unshare" id="unshare_entire_file" 
 name="unshare_entire_file" />
</form>
```

In server I am doing like this:

```
if request.POST.get('unshare_entire_file'):
    ...unshare for file
else
     ..unshare for user
```

But it turns out when I submit form using `jQuery` this doesn't work. I want to know which submit button is clicked and process accordingly. How can I do that?

Comment: What means "this doesn't work" ???

Comment: Here you are trying to submit a form with ID `unshare_form`, but you don't have any form with that ID, is it a typo from copying the code?

Comment: @maqjav: I only copied the submit button of the form. I have included form in my updated question.

Comment: @roasted: My function in server is not recognizing whether its unshare_entire_file or unshared_to_user. If I submit form in normal way without jquery it works.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this ?

```
$(function () {
    function unshareDialog(event, elem) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", elem.attr("id")).val(1);
        $("#unshare_form").prepend(input);
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 200,
            width: 365,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Unshare": function () {
                    $("#unshare_form").submit();
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    $('#unshare_entire_file,#unshare_to_user').click(function (e) {
        unshareDialog(e, $(this));
    });
});
```

It's clearly not optimal, but it should work